# combining idx and agg results after a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I am aggregating `tgt` within a `Ds` dataframe over `keyAgg` :
I can easily sum

```
Ds.groupby(Ds.keyAgg).tgt.agg([sum])
```

and derive the index of the minmium value in tgt for each group.

```
Ds.groupby(Ds.keyAgg).tgt.idxmin()
```

Is there a clean way to combine the two operations without an expensive `pd.merge()` of the two intermediate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pass list of aggregate function to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) if both return aggregate values:

```
Ds = pd.DataFrame({'keyAgg':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'tgt':   [4,8,2,0,4,5,1]})
print (Ds)
   keyAgg  tgt
0       1    4
1       1    8
2       2    2
3       2    0
4       3    4
5       3    5
6       3    1

df = Ds.groupby('keyAgg').tgt.agg(['sum', 'idxmin'])
print (df)
        sum  idxmin
keyAgg             
1        12       0
2         2       3
3        10       6
```

But if not like `cumsum` it is problem:

```
df = Ds.groupby('keyAgg').tgt.agg(['sum', 'cumsum'])
print (df)
    sum  cumsum
0   NaN       4
1  12.0      12
2   2.0       2
3  10.0       2
4   NaN       4
5   NaN       9
6   NaN      10
```

Then one possible solution is use custom function:

```
def func(x):
    a = x.sum()
    b = x.cumsum()

    return pd.DataFrame({'sum':a, 'cumsum':b})

Ds[['sum','cum']] = Ds.groupby('keyAgg').tgt.apply(func)
print (Ds)
   keyAgg  tgt  sum  cum
0       1    4   12    4
1       1    8   12   12
2       2    2    2    2
3       2    0    2    2
4       3    4   10    4
5       3    5   10    9
6       3    1   10   10
```

Or call aggregate function with `transform` and last join together:

```
df = pd.concat([Ds.groupby('keyAgg').tgt.transform('sum'),
                Ds.groupby('keyAgg').tgt.cumsum()], axis=1, keys=('sum','cum'))
print (df)
   sum  cum
0   12    4
1   12   12
2    2    2
3    2    2
4   10    4
5   10    9
6   10   10
```

Comment: where to find a complete reference of string values which are automatically interpreted as functions in pd.groupby().agg()

Comment: @00__00__00 - Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html#computations-descriptive-stats)